# converting simple JSON string into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

Code:

```
var jsonTest = {};
var testjson = ["xxxx.jpg","xxx.jpg","xxx.jpg"];
jsonTest = JSON.parse(testjson);
```

Error message:

```
Unable to parse JSON string.
```

However, when I test this in a JSON validator, it tells me that it is correct JSON.

Comment: It's not a string, it's an array! This makes no sense at all?

Comment: it's a JSON Array , see here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: JSON is a dataformat used for strings, there's no such thing as a JSON array / JSON object, you're confused.

Comment: Right, got you. Sorry - but what is the point of JSON.parse, sightly confused now on what it is used for

Comment: It's used to parse strings that are valid JSON

Comment: as in `JSON.parse( '{"key" : "value", "arr" : ["val1", "val2"]}' );` etc

Comment: @bobo2000: When you copy/paste it into JSONlint, you're copy pasting Unicode text whose formatting meets the requirements of the JSON standard. Imagine if you received that text from a server *(not part of a JavaScript program)*. You'd be just getting plain text with no capacity to look up its members. When you give that string to `JSON.parse`, it will validate it, and then eval it so that they text is interpreted by the JS interpreter, turning it into a valid JavaScript Array.

Comment: If you want to turn your array into JSON, you'd use `JSON.stringify( array )`

Comment: Because JSON is very similar to javascript, and an array with doublequotes pasted in as a string is valid in the linter.

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up

Comment: It's also important to realize that JSON isn't tied to JavaScript. The only connection is that its syntax is derived from syntax found in JavaScript. But the text data can be received by nearly any programming language and parsed and converted into objects that make sense for that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testjson` is already a valid javascript array, there is no need to parse it.

Comment: It's actually not JSON at all, and it's not an object, it's a regular javascript array.